# How to blur background image in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I want to overlay background image with some text, in Fabric.js is there a way to blur the background so the text will become more readable?

I have tried filter, but could only change the background image to grayscale, blur didn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with filter blur :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

Example : http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created this gist, it adds stack blurring as a filter to fabric class.

https://gist.github.com/human-a/25b7f58565b89de4e999ef2f4de1982c

```js
/**
 * Stack blur filter for fabricjs
 * Example:
 * obj.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur(6));
 * obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 *
 * Heavily inspired by:
 * https://gist.github.com/pierrickouw/2ab679159beee9d80ca6
 * http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
 * uses stackBlurCanvasRGBA function but could be swapped be stackBlurCanvasRGB
 * @see: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlur.js
 */

(function() {

    var fabric  = window.fabric,
    extend = fabric.util.object.extend;

    var mul_table = [
    512,512,456,512,328,456,335,512,405,328,271,456,388,335,292,512,
    454,405,364,328,298,271,496,456,420,388,360,335,312,292,273,512,
    482,454,428,405,383,364,345,328,312,298,284,271,259,496,475,456,
    437,420,404,388,374,360,347,335,323,312,302,292,282,273,265,512,
    497,482,468,454,441,428,417,405,394,383,373,364,354,345,337,328,
    320,312,305,298,291,284,278,271,265,259,507,496,485,475,465,456,
    446,437,428,420,412,404,396,388,381,374,367,360,354,347,341,335,
    329,323,318,312,307,302,297,292,287,282,278,273,269,265,261,512,
    505,497,489,482,475,468,461,454,447,441,435,428,422,417,411,405,
    399,394,389,383,378,373,368,364,359,354,350,345,341,337,332,328,
    324,320,316,312,309,305,301,298,294,291,287,284,281,278,274,271,
    268,265,262,259,257,507,501,496,491,485,480,475,470,465,460,456,
    451,446,442,437,433,428,424,420,416,412,408,404,400,396,392,388,
    385,381,377,374,370,367,363,360,357,354,350,347,344,341,338,335,
    332,329,326,323,320,318,315,312,310,307,304,302,299,297,294,292,
    289,287,285,282,280,278,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259
    ];
    var shg_table = [
    9, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17,
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19,
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24
    ];

    function BlurStack() {
        this.r = 0;
        this.g = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.a = 0;
        this.next = null;
    }

    fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter,{

        /**
        * Filter type
        */
        type: 'StackBlur',

        /**
        * Constructor
        */
        initialize: function(radius) { //radius of the blur
            this.radius = radius || 0;
            if(this.radius > 180) {
                this.radius = 180;
            }

            if(this.radius < 1) {
                this.radius = 0;
            }
        },

        /**
        * Applies blur to canvas element
        */
        applyTo: function(canvas) {
            // Don't apply blur if it's zero
            if (!this.radius) return;

            var radius = this.radius;
            var width = canvas.width;
            var height = canvas.height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageData;

            imageData = context.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height );

            var pixels = imageData.data;

            var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum, a_sum,
                r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum, a_out_sum,
                r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum, a_in_sum,
                pr, pg, pb, pa, rbs;

            var div = radius + radius + 1;
            var widthMinus1  = width - 1;
            var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
            var radiusPlus1  = radius + 1;
            var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * ( radiusPlus1 + 1 ) / 2;

            var stackStart = new BlurStack();
            var stack = stackStart;
            for ( i = 1; i < div; i++ ) {
                stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
                if ( i === radiusPlus1 ) var stackEnd = stack;
            }
            stack.next = stackStart;
            var stackIn = null;
            var stackOut = null;

            yw = yi = 0;

            var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
            var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];

            for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
                r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = 0;

                r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi] );
                g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1] );
                b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2] );
                a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3] );

                r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

                stack = stackStart;

                for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ ) {
                    stack.r = pr;
                    stack.g = pg;
                    stack.b = pb;
                    stack.a = pa;
                    stack = stack.next;
                }

                for( i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++ ) {
                    p = yi + (( widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i ) << 2 );
                    r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[p])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
                    g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[p+1])) * rbs;
                    b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[p+2])) * rbs;
                    a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[p+3])) * rbs;

                    r_in_sum += pr;
                    g_in_sum += pg;
                    b_in_sum += pb;
                    a_in_sum += pa;

                    stack = stack.next;
                }


                stackIn = stackStart;
                stackOut = stackEnd;
                for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
                    pixels[yi+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                    if ( pa !== 0 )
                    {
                        pa = 255 / pa;
                        pixels[yi]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                        pixels[yi+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                        pixels[yi+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                    } else {
                        pixels[yi] = pixels[yi+1] = pixels[yi+2] = 0;
                    }

                    r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                    g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                    b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                    a_sum -= a_out_sum;

                    r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                    g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                    b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                    a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    p = ( yw + ( ( p = x + radius + 1 ) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1 ) ) << 2;

                    r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
                    g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]);
                    b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]);
                    a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]);

                    r_sum += r_in_sum;
                    g_sum += g_in_sum;
                    b_sum += b_in_sum;
                    a_sum += a_in_sum;

                    stackIn = stackIn.next;

                    r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
                    g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
                    b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
                    a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

                    r_in_sum -= pr;
                    g_in_sum -= pg;
                    b_in_sum -= pb;
                    a_in_sum -= pa;

                    stackOut = stackOut.next;

                    yi += 4;
                }
                yw += width;
            }


            for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
                g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = r_sum = 0;

                yi = x << 2;
                r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi]);
                g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1]);
                b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2]);
                a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3]);

                r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
                g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
                b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
                a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

                stack = stackStart;

                for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ )
                {
                    stack.r = pr;
                    stack.g = pg;
                    stack.b = pb;
                    stack.a = pa;
                    stack = stack.next;
                }

                yp = width;

                for( i = 1; i <= radius; i++ )
                {
                    yi = ( yp + x ) << 2;

                    r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[yi])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
                    g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[yi+1])) * rbs;
                    b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[yi+2])) * rbs;
                    a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[yi+3])) * rbs;

                    r_in_sum += pr;
                    g_in_sum += pg;
                    b_in_sum += pb;
                    a_in_sum += pa;

                    stack = stack.next;

                    if( i < heightMinus1 )
                    {
                        yp += width;
                    }
                }

                yi = x;
                stackIn = stackStart;
                stackOut = stackEnd;
                for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
                {
                    p = yi << 2;
                    pixels[p+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
                    if ( pa > 0 )
                    {
                        pa = 255 / pa;
                        pixels[p]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                        pixels[p+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                        pixels[p+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                    } else {
                        pixels[p] = pixels[p+1] = pixels[p+2] = 0;
                    }

                    r_sum -= r_out_sum;
                    g_sum -= g_out_sum;
                    b_sum -= b_out_sum;
                    a_sum -= a_out_sum;

                    r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
                    g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
                    b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
                    a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    p = ( x + (( ( p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1 ) * width )) << 2;

                    r_sum += ( r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
                    g_sum += ( g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]));
                    b_sum += ( b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]));
                    a_sum += ( a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]));

                    stackIn = stackIn.next;

                    r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
                    g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
                        b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
                        a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

                        r_in_sum -= pr;
                        g_in_sum -= pg;
                        b_in_sum -= pb;
                        a_in_sum -= pa;

                        stackOut = stackOut.next;

                        yi += width;
                    }
                }
            context.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 );

        },

        /**
        * Returns object representation of an instance
        */
        toObject: function() {
            return extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
                radius: this.radius
            });
        }
    });

    fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur.fromObject = function(object) {
        return new fabric.Image.filters.StackBlur(object);
    };

})()
```